# Exclude Entity form fields in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In 1.x versions of Symfony it was recommended that you used useFields() and unset() to exclude entity property fields from being updated when excluded. Is there no easy way to do this in Symfony2?

Comment: you want to always exclude a field from being mapped ? if so simply dont map it to your ORM make it as a usual field in class and it will not get mapped

Comment: I apparently failed to include vital information in my question, sorry about that. In this particular case I am using FOSUserBundle and am extending the form type from BaseType. I want the field to be mapped when it is used but the field is added automatically even when I don't want it to be used.

Comment: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/remove-form-field

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example,suppose you dont want 'createdBy' to show in your form.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
 {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);        

    $builder->remove('createdBy');
 }
```